# Using HTML in Swing Applications

Tags: html, swing

Need some help here..I am trying to write a simple swing application which displays some text based on user actions. Its like help where user clicks on some url and he is redirected to that page. I have huge html code and I want to render it in swing components. I was able to do it in JDK1.6 software but not in JDK1.4. Is there any way we can render complex html in swing components in JDK 1.4 software?

I appreciate help.

Thanks
Padur

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) to render complex XHTML on Swing components. It does render very well and includes listener for links. Two caveats:

1. Document must be XHTML (not HTML)
2. I haven't tested on JRE 1.4 (which is out of support at Sun/Oracle)

Maybe it's worth a try.